# How to Navigate between Multiple Controls within a web part in sharepoint 2010 by using javascript

Tags: javascript

Please tell me how to Navigate between Multiple Controls within a web part in sharepoint 2007,
by using javascript.

Comment: Can you please explain your question in more detail? What do you mean exactly by "Navigate between Multiple Controls"?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is show and hide groups of controls, so you should put each set inside an HTML element such as a div or table for example, and give that an id. Then you can change the visibility of the alternate set when each is clicked. You would use something like:

```
document.getElementById('group1').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('group2').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

For the other group you would swap the hidden and visible values.